# Relationship of "ulimit -a" to fs.file-max

Tags: linux, ulimit, sysctl

I am on an `amazon linux` `ec2` instance and need to increase the files limit (to run spark).

It had been my recollection there were a way to do something like

```
ulimit -n 8192
```

But that is not "taking" `ulimit -a` still shows:

```
open files                      (-n) 1024
```

From `sudo su - root` the following was attempted:

```
sysctl  -w fs.file-max=16335
fs.file-max = 16335
```

So it seemed to work .. except ..:

```
open files                      (-n) 1024
```

Why are these commands not  "sticking" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found a suitable reference

https://glassonionblog.wordpress.com/2013/01/27/increase-ulimit-and-file-descriptors-limit/

[image]